# How can I identify Arabic letters in an image using Java?

Tags: image-processing, optical-char-recognition, java

I want to identify Egyptian car number plates that look like this:

[image: license plate image]

How can I do this in Java ?

I plan to do this in Android, as the user will catch the number plate with a camera and the results will be submitted to server.

Comment: For info on OCR in Java look at my answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786643/java-cyrillic-character-recognition-api/8800984#8800984

Comment: Do you have a template of all the possible number/letter shapes found on license plates?

Answer (score 8):

You have to do following methods:

**First step: Number plate extraction**

You can use [`OpenCV`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for this purpose. It has Java api. Also it is ported to [Android](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android).

**Second step : OCR**

OCR is used to recognise the letters on notice board.

You can train your own OCR for arabic letters and digits using OpenCV.

Or you can use tesseract-OCR. I think it supports arabic also.

---

Following paper will be useful for you: [Paper 1](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3am8SKo4Rg6nMJ%3asajjad.in/content/ALPR_paper.pdf%20number%20plate%20extraction%20in%20opencv&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi7u5_Y_zb1nG7PaeSjZ08DT2Nw7M5qcpqz_TqDVZDSCp0O-pSGBy2EbmkNLrmHoUnfzQeXcBdoH3OtIRG0YeimdcOQyK4JoNJ97CHK0GO5cPLIxskjedt1yY7c0ighaRYMaWF-&sig=AHIEtbShv3SGm7jzHgP8ptNy24nMjHn9Gg)

Also, [this site](http://www.dexmac.com/index.php/software/114-plategatewayqt) includes complete code for number plate extraction, but in C++. But it will be a good start.

Answer (score -1):

The link provides an algorithm to detect text from an image in Java... it works for English..

You can try for something similar for Arabic.
http://code.google.com/p/textdetection/source/browse/trunk/src/com/jpprade/text/detection/MainApp.java?r=7